# Remove numbering from sections/subsections but keep them in ToC?

Tags: header, pdf-generation, tableofcontents

I am writing a PDF where it is convinient for me to have a ToC where I might have to mix numbered and non-numbered section headers but I am struggling with finding how to do this automatically (eg just add a * to the section name or something like this).

```
 \section*
```

removes the numbering but it also removes the section from the ToC

Comment: This triggered a captcha request upon posting, is my question really so dumb the site thinks I am a robot? Haha

Comment: Are you using TeX? If so, please move your question on [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Comment: possible duplicate: [Adding unnumbered sections to TOC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11668/10704) ?